# When is this statement true? Never dealt with equations like these in logic before.

Tags: logic

When is this statement true? $$(\frac{1}{x}<10) => (x>\frac{1}{10})$$
I know that 
 for p=1 q=1 | p=>q=1
 for p=1 q=0 | p=>q=0
 for p=0 q=1 | p=>q=1
 for p=0 q=0 | p=>q=1 
But I don't know where to go from here

Comment: It is a simple statement in arithmetic which is true if $x$ is a positive real number (or positive rational). So the value $10$ for example is simply a number and $x$ is not the kind of entity which takes the values true or false.

Comment: So there is no catch? I thought I am definitely missing something

Comment: I think there is no catch

Comment: But isn't the whole statement true if both of equations are false? You suggest that the answer is that statement is true if x is a positive real number but how for x=1/10 it's not false? I don't get it

Comment: You are right of course. I am thinking informally and wrongly. You might consider the $x=0$ case carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think Mark Bennet was right the first time. According to text-books in logic, an implication is true iff the LHS is false and/or the RHS is true. So the implication in the question is true iff $1/x \ge 10$ and/or $x > 1/10$. Since $1/x \ge 10$ iff $0 < x \le 1/10$, the implication is true iff $x > 0$.